# Spring framework <form:form> how does it generate the action attribute?

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc

I'm using `<form:form>` on a JSP page in with Spring framework.
When I look at the generated page, I see `<form action="[the path of my page]">`.

`action="[the path of my page]"` is added automatically.

I could theoretically manually edit each `<form>` to add the `action=""` desired attribute (**edit:** using something like `${root}` in gerrytan's answer), but that would not be a practical option.

---

**Edit:** I cannot assume `/` to be the root path because it will be constantly changing since it's behind a proxy.)

---

How can I alter this automatic "behavior", so I concatenate a path at the beginning of [the path of my page]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will manually alter all form as 
and I will populate ${fullPathUrl} in some kind of filter method that gets called before every JSP page.

Answer (score 2):

Below are 2 common approaches I've seen being used along with their pros and cons:

**Always assume the context path is /**

You would put `<form:form action="/controller1/path1"`. The benefit of this approach is the URL always refer to consistent place regardless of what path used to serve the page. However this implies your app is deployed into `/` context path. If you had to change this (eg: due to reverse proxy / load balancer) then you'd have to do tons of find / replace

**Always lookup the context path using implicit variable**

This is my preferred approach. First define a jsp variable like this:

```
<c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
```

And whenever you have to refer to an internal path, use `${root}`

```
<form:form action="${root}/controller1/path1" ...
```

The cons of this approach is the variable `${root}` have to be declared on every single page. But when you change the context root rest assured all your references are still correct

You can also use `<spring:url>` or `<c:url>` as an alternative to this, or even better [use `HandlerInterceptor` to make the `root` attribute available automatically on all views](https://gerrydevstory.com/2014/03/06/using-handlerinterceptor-or-controlleradvice-to-make-spring-mvc-model-attribute-available-everywhere/)

**Edit**
It seems `${pageContext.request.servletPath}` is what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you very much but none of these solutions are available options (I edited my post).

Comment: Is `${pageContext.request.servletPath}` what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I will use something very similar. Thank you.